# How can I get the frequency value at given time with XAudio2?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, xaudio2

I've already loaded the `.wav` audio to the buffer with XAudio2 (Windows 8.1) and to play it I just have to use:

```
//start consuming audio in the source voice
/* IXAudio2SourceVoice* */ g_source->Start();

//play the sound
g_source->SubmitSourceBuffer(buffer.xaBuffer());
```

I wonder, **how can I get the frequency value at given time with XAudio2?**

Answer (score 2):

The question does not make much sense, a .wav file contains a great many frequencies.  It is the blend of them that makes it sound like music to your ears, instead of just an artificial generated tone.  A blend that's constantly changing.

A signal processing step is required to convert the samples in the .wav file from the time domain to the frequency domain.  Generally known as *spectrum analysis*, the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) is the standard technique.

A random Google hit on "xaudio2 fft" produced [this code sample](http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/5D67423E).  No idea how good it is, but something to play with to get the lay of the land.  You'll find more about it in [this gamedev question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9761/beat-detection-and-fft).

Comment: Thank you. Could you extend a second paragraph? I mean the time domain / frequency domain characteristics, differences and conversion (I guess I could plot the time domain as the 2d graph with x = time, y = amplitude, am I right?)? I've found the FFT implementations, but I am the very beginner in the physic aspect of audio processing.

Comment: I don't know where to start when you know so little about it yet.  You really do have to play with this if you don't want to read a book about it.